# How to test ASP NET ashx Handler With File Attached

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx

I have an c# ashx handler that detects files attached. It works fine.

However, I am relying on third party company to write software to send files to handler (long story). I need to test that my handler works, time difference between us and 3rd party company is becoming a nightmare.

The scenario is 3rd party software sends files every 30 seconds to handler and I need to test this works and without sounding stupid I thought I ask stackoverflow :)

I just want to test my ashx handler using test unit or whatever but no idea where to start. Typing in "handler.ashx?filename=12345.csv" is helpful but no actual file attached!

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, you have an ashx handler that you can upload files to and you want to test it.

I have attached a sample test that assumes an ashx handler that uses a POST request for file attachments.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestCallUploadHandler()
{
    const string FILE_PATH = "C:\\foo.txt";
    const string FILE_NAME = "foo.txt";
    string UPLOADER_URI =
        string.Format("http://www.foobar.com/handler.ashx?filename={0}", FILE_NAME);

    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(FILE_PATH))
    {
        var httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(UPLOADER_URI) as HttpWebRequest;
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        stream.CopyTo(httpRequest.GetRequestStream());

        var httpResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
        var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

        //Check the responsestring and see if all is ok
    }
}
```

Basically what you are doing is creating a WebRequest for **POST** and attaching the filestream to its request and filename to its query string.

Comment: What kind of security are you talking about ?

Comment: Sorry, it requires a username and password. Someone who wrote the code in the handler, coded it so it requires context.Request.Headers["Authorization"]

Comment: You can use **HttpWebRequest.Headers** to set any required headers

Comment: NetworkCredential networkCredential = new     NetworkCredential("username", "pwd");
      httpRequest.Credentials = networkCredential;

Comment: The response will be whatever the handler writes to the response stream. Most uploaders won't write anything. You can check the status to see if it is ok

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question and many thanks to @parapura:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestCallUploadHandler()
{
    const string FILE_PATH = "C:\\foo.txt";
    const string FILE_NAME = "foo.txt";
    string UPLOADER_URI = string.Format("http://www.foobar.com/handler.ashx?filename={0}", FILE_NAME);

    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(FILE_PATH))
    {
        var httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(UPLOADER_URI) as HttpWebRequest;
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";
        NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("username", "pwd"); 
        httpRequest.Credentials = networkCredential;
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        stream.CopyTo(httpRequest.GetRequestStream());

        byte[] authBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username:pwd".ToCharArray());
        httpRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(authBytes);

        var httpResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
        var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

        //Check the responsestring and see if all is ok
    }
}
```